# Under IPv6, how to discover all the IPv6 addresses on local link?

Tags: ipv6, arp

I need to discover (learn) all the IPs in my local network.

In IPv4, I can have one of the machines to listen to all the ARP broadcasting requests/responses, then I can build an IP/MAC table for all machines.

However, in IPv6, ARP is replaced with ICMPv6 Neighbor Solicitation message, and it is not broadcast message. One machine cannot listen to the Neighbor Solicitation/Advertisement messages between two other machines. Yes, ICMPv6's such design reduces the "shout-out" broadcasting overhead, but I also cannot learn all of my neighbors if I don't know their IPs in advance.

One workaround is to ping ff02::1. However, I found Linux will respond with such request, but Windows won't.

Much appreciated for any hints!

Comment: Network protocols are not made for this type of thing. What you suggest only works on layer-2 broadcast networks, e.g. ethernet, but there are many layer-2 network protocols that do not support broadcast (or multicast). Do you need to know the multiple IPv6 addresses on every host interface? Many hosts use IPv6 Privacy Extensions and Random addressing, so the IPv6 addresses can periodically change, although the Link-Local addresses will probably remain the same. By the way, ARP replies are not broadcast, only ARP requests are broadcast.

Comment: Multicast support is mandatory in IPv6. So in IPv6 network multicast based solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Most switches will not filter multicast packets on the LAN, so they are still broadcast on layer 2. If you disable the MAC address filter of your network card and put it in promiscuous mode you'll still see all the neighbour discovery traffic.

Comment: Thanks Sander. Yes, promiscuous mode will work. What I am looking for is a way without promiscuous mode. Turning that mode on will cause some performance degradation on the machine.

If Windows can reply to ping ff02::1 command (just like Linux), that would be nice. Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Pinging ff02::1 also only gets you one address from each host, and with IPv6 all hosts have multiple addresses. If you can capture all packets with MAC addresses starting with `33:33:ff:` you'll have what you need without capturing everything.

Comment: If you're looking for existing tools, take a look at `ndpmon`